# Londiste3 and pglogical replication on PostgreSQL Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two PostgreSQL databases, and one of the databases needs to replicate some of the tables from the other database (in real-time), we have been doing this with Londiste3 for quite some time now.

We are moving our databases to Amazon RDS, but from what I understand, we cannot install anything on them like you could on an EC2 server. So we cannot use Londiste3 or pglogical unless we use an ECC2 server to host the database (thus losing the backup features of RDS).

Does RDS support anything like this? I have read about "streaming replication" for read only instances, but that's not quite what we want. It would be fantastic if RDS has pglogical already installed, but I don't know if it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what Postgres RDS currently has:

```
test=> select version();
                                                 version
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit
(1 row)

test=> show rds.extensions;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                rds.extensions
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 address_standardizer,address_standardizer_data_us,bloom,btree_gin,
btree_gist,chkpass,citext,cube,dblink,dict_int,dict_xsyn,earthdistance,
fuzzystrmatch,hstore,hstore_plperl,intagg,intarray,ip4r,isn,ltree,
pgcrypto,pgrowlocks,pgstattuple,pg_buffercache,pg_prewarm,
pg_stat_statements,pg_trgm,pg_visibility,plcoffee,plls,plperl,plpgsql,
pltcl,plv8,postgis,postgis_tiger_geocoder,postgis_topology,postgres_fdw,
sslinfo,tablefunc,test_parser,tsearch2,tsm_system_rows,tsm_system_time,
unaccent,uuid-ossp
```

I also would be happy to see there londiste (which implies having pgq as well, btw; so it's not that easy and walks us away from Postgres itself) and especially pglogical.